# Docking Station Problem

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb

I bought a Asus SimPro Dock. I know it is not officially compatible, but I had a friends that uses it at works without problems. I connected it to my MacBook Pro 16 (2019) and it works for all the functionalities, except for the external monitor, the docking station instead works with a dell notebook and with my MacBook Pro 15 (2016). Initially I thought that the problem was Big Sur (my old MacBook has Catalina), but after a clean installation of Catalina also on the 16", the docking station continues to not working. Any advices?

EDIT monitor is a simple 24" HP, it has both HDMI and VGA and I tested both of them. They both works when connecting docking station to MacBook Pro 2016, and neither of them work with the new 2019 16" one

EDIT2 This morning I notice that the monitor works correctly at boot, until I put password. After that, OS start loading and after a couple of seconds the monitor shutted down

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Would you edit this to narrow down a specific external monitor. Model, make, exactly which cable connects it to the dock, ideally.

Comment: Which monitor cable connection? DisplayPort, HDMI or VGA? Typically DP works better than HDMI in most cases.

Comment: thanks for the welcome, I add other details